# Find the derivative of a negative fractional exponent.

Tags: calculus

Using the definition of the derivative

$$f'(x) = \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$$

Find  $f'(x)$ of $f(x) = 4x^{-3⁄2}$.

So far I have moved the the negative exponent to a denominator and made it positive.

$$f'(x) = \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{4}{h}\left(\frac {1}{(x+h)^{3/2}}-\frac {1}{x^{3/2}}\right)$$

At this point I consider how to move on, I considered re writing the denominator as a radical and then multiplying by the conjugate but I am not sure of the way forward.

$$\frac {1}{\sqrt[2]{(x+h)^{3}}}$$

Comment: notation fixed up.

Comment: Writing a radical form won't help with the calculation.  Complete the subtraction of the ratios, then multiply the numerator and denominator by the conjugate of the _numerator  difference_.  After some algebra, you will have a free factor of $ \ h \ $ in the numerator that will cancel the $ \ h \ $ in the denominator.

Comment: If you notice, you get the $\infty-\infty$ indeterminate form, which is usually solved by combining the fractions and conjugation to form $0/0$ or $\infty/\infty$ form.

Comment: Reduce to a single fraction and multiply and divide by the same quantity: $(x^{3/2}+(h+x)^{3/2})$.